# Normed (non-Trivial) Vector Space over R or C - Every Point in Open Set is a Limit Point?

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

I think this is true, but after searching can't find the confirmation I would expect. **So I would appreciate confirmation or correction.**

Proof:

A non-trivial vector space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ contains at least two different vectors, $0$ and $v \ne 0$ and by algebraic closure contains all linear combinations.

For any vector $a$ in an open set $A$ there is therefore $b \in V$ with $b \ne a$ and all $w_x = a + x.b \in V$ where $x \in R \ge 0$.

Since $A$ is open then there is some $r$ such that $ a \in B_r (a) \subset A$

$\|a - w_x\| = \|-x\cdot b\| = x\cdot\|b\|$  and **for any $s > 0$** there is some $x(s)$ such that $x\cdot\|b\| < s$ and therefore $w_{x(s)} \in B_s(a)$.

So, for any  $s$ with  $r > s > 0$ then there is $w_{x(s)}$ with $a \ne w_{x(s)} \in A$ and $w_{x(s)} \in B_s(a) \subset B_r (a) \subset A$.

If $C$ is any open set containing $a$ then there is $t$ with $ a \in B_t (a) \subset C$. So for $s < min(r, t)$ then $w_x(s) \in A$ and $\in C$, i.e. every open set that contains $a$ contains a point of $A$ different to $a$ and so $a$ is a limit point of $A$.

Extension:

In fact $C$ contains all the points $w_x$ with $0 < x \le x(s)$ and so $a$ is a "condensation point" of $A$

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks. I'd have expected to be able to easily find this as a standard result: any suggestions why not ?

Comment: The reason is probably that it is too elementary to be stated as a separate theorem/proposition/lemma, although it might be stated in a textbook as an exercise.

Comment: @LeeMosher. Thanks again.

Comment: More generally, any non-singleton convex set (open or not) in a vector space (normed, topological, etc. so that "limit point" makes sense) over the real or complex numbers has this property. In fact, even any non-singleton star convex set in such a space. In all these cases we actually have a "line segment of points" in the set joining up to any specified point in the set, so any point in the set being a limit point of the set is very strongly satisfied (and the reasoning is pretty trivial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your argument is right, but I find it too complicated. Here is a simpler argument. The key (trivial) fact is that if $t>0$ and $v\ne0$, then $tv\ne0$.

Now take $A$ open, $a\in A$. Fix any nonzero vector $v$. Then, as you say, there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r(a)\subset A$. 
$$
\|(a+tv)-a\|=\|tv\|=t\|v\|,
$$
so $$\lim_{t\to0}a+tv=a. $$ When $t<r/\|v\|$, we have $a+tv\in B_r(a)\subset A$, so $a+tv\in A$ for all $t\in[0,r/\|v\|)$. And $a+tv\ne a$ if $t\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in any topological space an isolated point of an open set is isolated in the whole space.

It follows immediately that if a homogeneous topological space has any open subset with an isolated point, it must be a discrete space.